# Strangeness with type constructors in python

Tags: python, constructor

In python I can do things like:

```
d = dict()
i = int()
f = float()
l = list()
```

but there is no constructor for strings

```
>>> s = string()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Why is that?  Or, IS there a constructor for string types?

Also, following the definitions above,

```
d['a'] = 1
```

works, but

```
>>> l[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

does not.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, you want `str`, not `string`.

But to answer your other question, lists cannot be extended by assignment. If you try to assign outside the bounds of a list, you get an error. On the other hand, dictionaries *have* no bounds in any meaningful sense; they have only defined keys and undefined keys.

Think of a dictionary as a bag of objects tied together, and a list as a tray with a fixed number of compartments. You can throw a pair of things into the bag anytime, but you can't put something in a tray's compartment if no such compartment exists. You have to create the compartment, using [`append`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or something similar. Since your "tray" has *no* compartments yet, `l[0] = x` fails.

Comment: Thanks.  My fault for not being as familiar as I should about lists.  I've used append a lot, but didn't know I HAD to do it that way.  Also, I searched the python docs, and found no reference to str.  I'm puzzled about where I should have looked.  Anyway, you and others did straighten me out.

Answer (score 3):

You meant:

```
a = str()
```

I believe. Then everything works.

And as to the distinction between `d['a']` and `l[0]`: `d` is a dictionary, which has a sparse representation of the elements stored. Whereas a list (`l`) represents data densely: so if you had:

`l = [1,2]`

And you subsequently wrote:

`l[200] = 31`

It would imply, as well as assigning to element 200, to be entirely consistent, putting some arbitrary values in `l[3:199]` as well.

Answer (score 1):

yes we've `str()`:

```
>>> s=str()
>>> s
''
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin function for string creation:

```
s = str()  # s == ''
```

As far as your assignment into a list vs your assignment into a dictionary:

Dictionaries are unordered, so it makes complete sense to be able to add a key value pair anywhere at any time.  In fact, dictionary keys don't even need to be the same type  (`d[1]='foo'; d["string"]='bar'`).  Lists however are ordered.  Consider the following:

```
a=list()
a[1]='foo'
```

What should the language do in that scenario?  `a[0]` hasn't yet been defined, so the language would have to make something up in order to maintain the ordered-ness of lists, or throw an error.  Assigning to `a[0]` or the next element in the sequence (e.g. `a=list(); a[0]='bar'`) is a very special case and from reading the "Zen of Python", special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.  I would guess this is why Guido decided to force the list element to exist before you can assign to it (e.g `a=list(); a.append('foo'); a[0]='bar'`)